# How to put product title inside product thumbnail

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

[image: from this]

I want to change the position of the product title in archive-product page from below the thumbnail to the inside of the thumbnail.

[image]

i have a plugin telling me that the file responsible for this content is archive-product.php and inside i found the code

```
if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

    woocommerce_product_loop_start();

    if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();

            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
             *
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
    }

    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
```

What is the right way to style it as on the example ?

Any advice on what i am doing wrong will be hardly appreciated​

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `archive-product.php` in your theme. For that, you have to create a woocommerce folder and place this template inside that folder by following the same folder structure of the woocommerce. 
After doing that place your custom code in that file. Add some custom class and apply CSS to it.

Comment: This is exactly what i've made, I've already override many of the woocommerce files, so I am familiar with its structure, but in this case using the code from my post, doesn't change anything. also tried with some custom class and applying CSS to it.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS version**

```css
.product {
  position: relative;
}

.product img {
  width: 100%;
}

.product p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
  <p>Product Title</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I cant find the right place to execute this code since the archive-product.php page content is only hooks and once written the `<div class="product">` and trying to apply `<img src="hook" />` brakes the page..

Comment: main post updated providing what I've think is the code which needs to be manipulated